# Node JS send empty JSON body

Tags: node.js, post

I have the code below which is supposed to send a POST request but with an empty JSON body:

```
request.post({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "data_digest": 'muZ7EcapQZVb77RF',
        "partner_code": "ebfebc241db9b9c1a",
        "msg_type": "GET_BASEDATA_TRANSPORT",
        "msg_id": '1590464383047',
        "Accept-Language": "zh-cn"
    },
    json: true,
    body: {}
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

However this keeps returning

```
'System Exception:\r\ntype org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException\r\nmessage:Could not find acceptable representation'
```

But using Postman I'm able to correctly send POST request with the exact same headers but just an empty {} in the Body parameter with Raw format.

How can I send a POST request with an empty JSON body in Node JS?

Comment: My initial assessment was wrong because I confused the API of `request` with `request-promise`'s which I always use. The `json: {}` works fine. The issue is something else, see my new answer below - you need `Accept: */*`. I deleted my old answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of sending the body is fine. If you'd look at the actual request sent (for example using Fiddler or Wireshark) you'd see the body is sent correctly. The problem is something else - instead you'd see that the headers are *not* the exact same.

Using `json` (either with `json: true` and `body`, or as you do it, with `json` as object) also automatically sets the `Accept` header to `application/json` and attempts to parse the response as JSON.

It seems that this server `chiguotest.ytoglobal.com` has a bug, where it returns JSON but does not handle the `Accept` header correctly (I tested it and it seems the server "thinks" it is returning `text/plain`). So `request` is (correctly) telling the server "I expect you to return JSON", but the server says "What, JSON? No I don't know how to return JSON, only text, sorry.". Yet, it in fact does return JSON.

You can circumvent this server bug by explicitely sending an `Accept: */*` header:

```js
request.post({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "data_digest": 'muZ7EcapQZV',
        "partner_code": "ebfebc241db9b9c",
        "msg_type": "GET_BASEDATA_TRANSPORT",
        "msg_id": '1590464383047',
        "Accept-Language": "zh-cn",
        "Accept": "*/*"
    },
    json: true,
    body: {}
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

My output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "productKinds": [
      {
        "productCnname": "(美国)测试用-不拉G单号",
        "productCode": "1",
        "productEnname": "1",
        "productServerhawbcodeNeed": "Y"
      },
      {
        "productCnname": "散客可见产品",
        "productCode": "111",
        "productEnname": "内部产品",
        "productServerhawbcodeNeed": "N"
      },
      ... many more entries ...
   ]
  },
  "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
  "errorMsg": "成功",
  "status": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent the past 24 hours looking everywhere and no solutions 